# How to instantiate and push an (additional) storyboard into my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

My app is mainly constructed without storyboards.
However, I have created just one for the registration of users.

This storyboard consists of a navigation controller containing 2 views controllers.
The first one is called "FirstVC", and the one "SecondVC" (this one would not be used for my question).

I am trying to push it in the AppDelegate.m file (trying various ways, see below) but my screen is always black.

**attempt 1**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FirstRegistration" bundle:nil];
    FirstVC *fvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstVC"];
    UINavigationController *navController =(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];
   return YES;
```

}

**attempt 2**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FirstRegistration" bundle:nil];
    FirstVC *fvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = fvc;
    return YES;
}
```

**Note :** I've set the FirstVC scene to FirstVC in the identifier Custom Class section and also set the storyboard ID to FirstVC. However I have not touched to the NavigationController scene, should I just set the custom class to UINavigationController ?

[image]

Comment: have you set identifier "FirstVC" in storyboard?

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I have, however as I said (see update), I don't know what to do with the navigation controller scene.

Comment: set that property in navigationVC and load that one instead of firstVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try adding this line

**[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FirstRegistration" bundle:nil];
    FirstVC *fvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = fvc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; //**Add this**
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have completely forgotten to add this line ! It works now !

Comment: Great .. keep coding :)